# How to run a code chunk from LeetCode in the local IDE?

Tags: java, string, eclipse, data-structures

All Leetcode questions don't seem to have main methods, I wonder how I could run the code in a local IDE(say, eclipse)? For instance, I was trying to run this one:

Q: Write a method/function to replace all the space in String s to "%20".

The code:

```
public class ReplaceSpace {

public String replaceSpace(String s) {
    StringBuilder res = new StringBuilder();
    for(Character c : s.toCharArray()) {
        if(c == ' ')
            res.append("%20");
        else 
            res.append(c);
    }
    return res.toString();
    
}// that'll work in the Leetcode editor

public static void main(String[] args) {
    String s = "We are happy.";
    System.out.print(s.replaceSpace); //reports "cannot be resolved to a type" error

}
```

}

Also, if anyone could explain a little why Leetcode editor could run code without the main method it would be great.

Comment: There is no main function in the leetcode, but doesn't it work if you run it on the generated function by default?

Comment: They have the main method indeed. But in another class. So in the main method containing class, they create a new instance of the ReplaceSpace class. And then from that class calls your replaceSpace() method.

Comment: @Amimul Ehsan Rahi  I wonder if I could make a similar setting in the local IDE? (that applies to all Leetcode questions that have "Solution" as their class name)

Answer (score 1):

To test the code in your local IDE, simply provide your own main. The pre-written code usually contains non-static methods. This gives you two ways to test your code.

### Add static

```
public class ReplaceSpace 
{
    public static String replaceSpace(String s)
    {
        ...
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        System.out.println (replaceSpace("We are happy"));
    }
}
```

### Create object

```
public class ReplaceSpace 
{
    public String replaceSpace(String s)
    {
        ...
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        ReplaceSpace rs = new ReplaceSpace();
        System.out.println (rs.replaceSpace("We are happy"));
    }
}
```

Comment: What if the parameter is a ListNode type(for instance, "ListNode head" that is int[1,3,2])? I wonder how to write the parameter in the sysout statement.

Comment: If the method accepts an parameter of any type `a`, you have to create one in main and then test it.

Answer (score 0):

`replaceSpace` is a method of `ReplaceSpace` class and not `String` class.  `String` is the return type for `replaceSpace` method. You're trying to call the `replaceSpace` method on the `String` class object.

In order to run the code, you need to instantiate an object of `ReplaceSpace` class and then call the `replaceSpace` method on its object by passing the string which you want to replace as a parameter. Like so:

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
    ReplaceSpace rs = new ReplaceSpace();
    String replacedString = rs.replaceSpace("We are happy.");
    System.out.println(replacedString);
}
```

Another way is to make the `replaceSpace` method static and call the method without an object instantiation.

As to how Leetcode runs the code behind the scenes, they don't need to use `main` methods to run your code. They just have unit tests written for your function with exhaustive test cases to test your solution rather than running your code via main methods.